# Boto batch with a local secondary index

Tags: boto

I have a dynamodb table with a local secondary index and doing a batch get on the secondary index would save me a lot of trouble.

Is it possible to do a batch operation on a table using the local secondary index of that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by the DynamoDB API.  The `BatchGetItem` requires a list of primary keys as a parameter.

But can't you just do a query based on the secondary index?